DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs: Infinite repainting loop?
I'm trying to customize certain cells in a WinForms DataGridView, but I'm running into an issue where the painting event is firing over and over again non-stop forever, even when not scrolling through the lines. Basically, when starting the application it does do everything it's supposed to, but there is a constant flicker and it takes nearly 20 seconds to draw the entire GUI. For obvious reasons this is not ideal.
I was able to eliminate the flickering by adding double buffering to the DataGridView, but that is just masking the issue as it's still constantly redrawing in the background. I don't know if there's a problem with my code or it's a bug in forms, but if I just set the DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle using Single then the problem does not occur. It's only when I try doing multiple actions or if I use a different border style. For example, Inset and Outset border styles alone cause the redrawing/flickering, as does just changing the font.
The basic idea is that I want to mimic "headers" every so many rows, that appear different than normal rows. I am only using a single column, so in a way I'm trying to make the DataGridView appear more like a ListView where there is no border between rows. But with the difference of being able to have fake headers every, let's say, 20-30 rows. There is a few other things I wanted to do as well, such as change the BackColor of the "fake headers", but I figured I would try to get help now because I'm pretty much at a loss. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
private void dataList_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView     dataList     = ((DataGridView)(sender));
    DataGridViewRow  dataListRow  = dataList.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    DataGridViewCell dataListCell = dataListRow.Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

    string dataTitle = dataListCell.Value.ToString();
    char   firstChar = dataTitle.ToCharArray()[0];

    Font  lineFont = dataList.Font;
    float fontSize = lineFont.Size + (float)2.25;

    FontFamily fontFamily = lineFont.FontFamily;

    if (firstChar == '=')
    {
        dataListRow.Height = 26;

        lineFont = new Font(fontFamily, fontSize, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);

        dataListCell.Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle { Font = lineFont };

        e.AdvancedBorderStyle.All = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.Single;
    }
    else 
    {
        e.AdvancedBorderStyle.All = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
    }
}


Changing Height in CellPainting is a bad idea.

Resetting the Style in the CellPainting event is also a bad idea. Everything that causes the Cell to change aspect, except setting the Properties provided by DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs, is a bad idea -- You have curious upper / lower case mishaps there

Yeah I was editing some of it in browser, wasn't a total copy and paste and I messed up "lineFont". If modifying these properties in a paint event is not the way the go, is there any other way to modify the height / font of a single cell or row?

Ok I figured out a better way to go about this. The only thing that can be done via the CellPainting event is drawing the border as Single without it going into an infinite painting loop. Rather than try to alter the properties here, I opted to alter the height and apply a DataGridViewCellStyle to the cell while it was being populated.
for (int i = 0; i < dataSheet.Count(); i++)
{
    string dataTitle  = dataSheet[i];
    char[] titleArray = dataTitle.ToCharArray();

    if (titleArray[0] == '=')
    {
        string newTitle = "";
        foreach (char titleChar in titleArray)
        {
            if (titleChar != '=')
            {
                newTitle += titleChar;
            }
        }
        dataTitle = newTitle;
    }
    dataList.Rows.Add(dataTitle);

    DataGridViewRow  dataListRow  = dataList.Rows[i];
    DataGridViewCell dataListCell = dataListRow.Cells[0];

    Font       listFont   = dataList.Font;
    float      fontSize   = listFont.Size + (float)2.25;
    FontFamily fontFamily = listFont.FontFamily;

    dataListRow.Height = 26;

    dataListCell.Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle()
    {
        Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
        BackColor = SystemColors.Menu,
        Font = new Font(fontFamily, fontSize, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point),
        ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText,
        SelectionBackColor = SystemColors.Highlight,
        SelectionForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText
    };
}

Rather than check the first character of the string in the CellPainting event, the BackColor is known since it won't be white like the normal cells, so I've used that for the detection method.
// Use the style to filter out the correct nodes.
DataGridViewCellStyle dataListStyle = dataListCell.Style;

// Now check the style backcolor.
if (dataListStyle.BackColor == SystemColors.Menu)
{
    // Set the border style to show the border.
    e.AdvancedBorderStyle.All = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.Single;
}
else
{
    // Remove the border for game titles.
    e.AdvancedBorderStyle.All = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
}

I thank those who commented to let me know I was on the wrong track trying to do this in the paint event. This led me to figuring out that styles can be applied on a per-cell basis, and row height can be changed individually. With the new method of altering most properties after the row's creation, the paint event only needs to worry about drawing the border around the cell, which is the only thing it can do without running forever.

Just replace the line
dataListCell.Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle { Font = lineFont };

with
dataListCell.Style.Font = lineFont;

